# org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException though setting proxy

Tags: java, proxy, timeout, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient to send get requests. It works fine when I am at home.

But when I run my application with my company's network, I will have  `org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException` although I tried below ways to set proxy:

1.

```
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "cn-proxy.cn.oracle.com");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

2. Add to the VM arguments at Run configuration

   ```
       -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyserver.com  
       -Dhttp.proxyPort=80
   ```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 private static long TIME_OUT_IN_SECONDS = 120;

 httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
 long requestEndTime = new Date().getTime();
 long timeOfRequest = (requestEndTime - requestStratTime) / 1000;
 if (httpResponse == null && timeOfRequest > TIME_OUT_IN_SECONDS) {
      throw new TimeOutException();
 }
```

This occurs when data takes too much time to respond that is requested, you are missing throws timeout exception.